# Проблема с авторизацией MySQLi

Tags: mysqli, авторизация

Всем привет. Пишу авторизацию для административной панели, и вот не могу понять, что вообще происходит - в условия не попадает, вардампил, посмотрите функцию, может что подскажите

```
function auth($login,$password)
{
    global $db;
    // Проверим включен ли модуль Пользователи

    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE title = 'user'") or die('Ошибка #783462');
    if (!$sql->num_rows){
        echo "Ошибка, модуль пользователей отключен";
    }else{
        unset($sql);
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ? AND password = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("ss",$login,$password);
        $sql->execute();
        // проверим есть ли такие данные в БД
            if (!$sql->num_rows){
                return $message = "Такого пользователя нет!";
            }else{
                $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
                $_SESSION['a_user'] = $login;
                header('Location: /'); 
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: А по какой ветке идёт выполнение?

Comment: он условие не проходит  if (!$sql->num_rows){

Comment: Что значит "в условия не попадает" и "условие не проходит"?

Т.е. проверка "if (!$sql->num_rows)..." даже не выполняется?

Или выполняется, но всегда срабатывает условие "!$sql->num_rows"?


UPD: так я смотрю у вас два условия "if (!$sql->num_rows)..." У вас на каком запросе спотыкается? На первом (проверка модуля) или на втором (проверка пользователя)?